# read value from property file for from URI in apache camel

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

Below is my camel context, but reading vlaue from property file doesnt work,  it is not listening to Queue which is mentioned in queueName. Is using poll 
       enrich A good Idea, because it uses direct component?

```
   <bean id="bridgePropertyPlaceholder" 
    class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:/config/queue.properties"/>
    </bean> 

    <Route>
    <from uri="activemq:queue:{{queueName}}/>
    .......
    </Route>
```

Comment: Does the bundle starts? What errors do you get in the logs?

Comment: You're missing a closing quote in the 'from' line - copy/paste error?

Comment: try with this `${queueName}`

Comment: did you define `activemq` component properly to connect to the broker? In the uri `activemq` is a bean id of class `org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent` which defines a broker connection.

Comment: @pvpkiran - inside Camel Context and Camel Route elements it can be only `{{queueName}}`, Spring notation `${}` does not work.

Comment: Thanks guys for your response, but it workekd with <from uri="activemq:queue:{{queueName}}/> , i am using Springs BridgePropertyPlaceholder for reading from property file